# Rails nginx directory index is forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, production-environment

Hello i setup my first webserver for rails but when i copy rails app and run nginx server, im getting 403 error in browser and error.log says that directory index is forbidden.. the error is solved when i create index.html in public folder in rails app but why rails is not started ? (server was compilled with passenger) and bundle install inside rails app works. thank you.

**/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf**

```
http {
    passenger_root /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/gems/passenger-4.0.14;
    passenger_ruby /home/lukas/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails3/ruby;
    include /opt/nginx/conf.d/*.conf; 
...
}
```

**/opt/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
 listen *:80;
 server_name hostname.org www.hostname.org

 passenger_enabled on;
 rails_env production;
 root /var/www/default/public;

 error_log /opt/nginx/logs/vhosts/default/error.log;
 access_log /opt/nginx/logs/vhosts/default/access.log combined;
}
```

**folder permissions**

```
lukas@webserver:/var/www$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x 13 lukas lukas 4096 Aug 30 12:26 default
```

im **starting nginx** with

```
sudo /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

**/opt/nginx/logs/vhosts/default/error.log**

```
2013/08/30 12:48:08 [error] 32643#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/default/public/" is forbidden, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx needs to have read permissions for the file as well as execute permissions for every hierarchical parent directory of the file to chdir to it and also Sometimes, the index directive does not contain the desired directory index.

Comment: i did run `chown -R root:root default/` but it doesnt help, what else i have to do ?

Comment: now i did `rvmsudo rails new default` and it run welcome screen but button `about your app configuration` says `Not Found 404`

Comment: routes.rb doesnt work and in error.log i have `open() "/var/www/default/public/rails/info/properties" failed` i dont understand it, on testing server it was all working